# Same algorithm, multiple input and output type possibility in Go?

Tags: go

I'm currently using [draw2d](https://github.com/llgcode/draw2d) lib to render some image. I noticed the core algorithm and method are the same for building [SVG](https://github.com/llgcode/draw2d/tree/master/draw2dsvg), or [PNG](https://github.com/llgcode/draw2d/tree/master/draw2dimg) images.

I do need to render this images as SVG (for web use) and PNG (for PDF use)

The only difference is at the entry type and output.

for PNG rendering I've

as input:

```
var gc *draw2dimg.GraphicContext
var img *image.RGBA

img = image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, xSize, ySize))
gc = draw2dimg.NewGraphicContext(img)
```

as output:

```
draw2dimg.SaveToPngFile(FileName, img)
```

and for SVG I've:

as input:

```
var gc *draw2dsvg.GraphicContext
var img *draw2dsvg.Svg

img = draw2dsvg.NewSvg()
gc = draw2dsvg.NewGraphicContext(img)
```

as output:

```
draw2dsvg.SaveToSvgFile(FileName, img)
```

between input and output I've the same implementation.

Is there any way in Go to use different input type and get the same implementation without have to duplicate some code?

Comment: The only thing that's the same are your variables names, the functions and types involved are different. Are you looking to redesign the `draw2d` API?

Comment: Try to refactor your code by moving the *same algorithm part* (code between *input* and *output*) to separate function which accept `gc draw2d.GraphicContext` as its argument.

Comment: @putu problem is, they aren't even using the same context type.  It's not a `draw2d.GraphicContext`, it's a `draw2dsvg.GraphicContext` and a `draw2dimg.GraphicContext`, and these are concrete structure types defined in each package.  There's literally no common type point between these algorithms.  The inputs are different, the output types are different, and the algorithms themselves are different.  As JimB said, the only similarities are the variable names.

Comment: @Kaedys yes, each context is a concrete structure type, but they implement `draw2d.GraphicContext` interface.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, _that_ could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, try to refactor your code by moving the core algorithm part into a function or may be to a different package. To illustrate the idea, bellow is the refactored version of example in https://github.com/llgcode/draw2d README.

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"

    "github.com/llgcode/draw2d"
    "github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dimg"
    "github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dpdf"
    "github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dsvg"
)

func coreDraw(gc draw2d.GraphicContext) {
    // Set some properties
    gc.SetFillColor(color.RGBA{0x44, 0xff, 0x44, 0xff})
    gc.SetStrokeColor(color.RGBA{0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0xff})
    gc.SetLineWidth(5)

    // Draw a closed shape
    gc.BeginPath()    // Initialize a new path
    gc.MoveTo(10, 10) // Move to a position to start the new path
    gc.LineTo(100, 50)
    gc.QuadCurveTo(100, 10, 10, 10)
    gc.Close()
    gc.FillStroke()
}

func main() {
    format := "svg"

    switch format {
    case "png":
        dest := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 297, 210.0))
        gc := draw2dimg.NewGraphicContext(dest)
        coreDraw(gc)
        draw2dimg.SaveToPngFile("hello.png", dest)
    case "pdf":
        dest := draw2dpdf.NewPdf("L", "mm", "A4")
        gc := draw2dpdf.NewGraphicContext(dest)
        coreDraw(gc)
        draw2dpdf.SaveToPdfFile("hello.pdf", dest)
    case "svg":
        img := draw2dsvg.NewSvg()
        gc := draw2dsvg.NewGraphicContext(img)
        coreDraw(gc)
        draw2dsvg.SaveToSvgFile("hello.svg", img)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to achieve code sharing in Go would be through the use of [interfaces](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces). See if you can break down the steps of your image algorithm into interface methods. Then those methods can be driven in a generic way by a single piece of code that works across all image formats, as in the `runAlgorithm` function below.

```
package main

import (
    "image"

    "github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dimg"
    "github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dsvg"
)

// Common algorithm that is implemented for various image formats.
type ImageAlgorithm interface {
    CreateImage(xSize, ySize int)
    CreateGraphicsContext()
    SaveImage(fileName string)
}

type RGBAAlgorithm struct {
    gc  *draw2dimg.GraphicContext
    img *image.RGBA
}

func (alg *RGBAAlgorithm) CreateImage(xSize, ySize int) {
    alg.img = image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, xSize, ySize))
}

func (alg *RGBAAlgorithm) CreateGraphicsContext() {
    alg.gc = draw2dimg.NewGraphicContext(alg.img)
}

func (alg *RGBAAlgorithm) SaveImage(fileName string) {
    draw2dimg.SaveToPngFile(fileName, alg.img)
}

type SvgAlgorithm struct {
    gc  *draw2dsvg.GraphicContext
    img *draw2dsvg.Svg
}

func (alg *SvgAlgorithm) CreateImage(xSize, ySize int) {
    alg.img = draw2dsvg.NewSvg()
}

func (alg *SvgAlgorithm) CreateGraphicsContext() {
    alg.gc = draw2dsvg.NewGraphicContext(alg.img)
}

func (alg *SvgAlgorithm) SaveImage(fileName string) {
    draw2dsvg.SaveToSvgFile(fileName, alg.img)
}

func runAlgorithm(alg ImageAlgorithm) {
    // input
    alg.CreateImage(100, 100)
    alg.CreateGraphicsContext()

    // output
    alg.SaveImage("out")
}

func main() {
    runAlgorithm(&RGBAAlgorithm{})
    runAlgorithm(&SvgAlgorithm{})
}
```